# How do I run the laravel project with postgresql? (how to run localhost/projectname on web browser?)

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, browser

In Xampp, mysql is already have. The project folders have to move under 'htdocs' folder. And then, localhost/projectfolder can be run on browser.
With postgresql, I have no idea how to run on browser. (I have connected pgsql and project)

Is there any idea to run on browser after connecting with project and pgsql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `.env` file in your laravel project. You will see things like the following

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

You should change it accordingly. Then you can run it with XAMPP(apache server) without any trouble.

Comment: If so, Is Apache Server the only essential thing to run the project on web browser, whatever the database connection (mysql or pgsql)?

Comment: Yes. No problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've really understood it :)